# Why "git checkout master" didn't revert file content back to previously?

Tags: git, git-branch

Say, if the file `foo` is committed already, having the content of

```
just a simple line
```

now a `git checkout -b issue57` is done to create a branch and switch to it (say, that issue57 branch is to last 2 days for development), and a line `footer added` is added to the file for now, and then a `git commit -a -m "add a footer to the file"`.

So now the file `foo` has the content

```
just a simple line
footer added
```

When a "hot fix" or "quick fix" is needed, I thought the command `git checkout master` should be used, and now the content of the file `foo` should be back to that just one single line.  But when I do `more foo`, the file has both lines, why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works just fine for me:

```
$ more foo
just a simple line
$ echo "footer added" >> foo
$ git checkout -b issue57
M   foo
Switched to a new branch 'issue57'
$ git commit -a -m "add a footer to the file"
[issue57 c397054] add a footer to the file
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
$ more foo
just a simple line
footer added
$ git checkout master
$ more foo
just a simple line
```

Maybe you have committed the file before `git checkout -b issue57`?

Comment: yes, I have committed it... but, let's say that version is version 1.0, I got to commit it, before starting on issue57 and create a branch and switch to it, isn't that the case?

Comment: by the way, I do `git checkout -b issue57` first, and then add the line `footer added`

Comment: You can do it either way since changes are preserved when doing a `git checkout`. You just have to be on branch `issue57` when *committing* your changes.

Comment: by the way, I read through the commands, and it turned out that when I commit the file after the footer is added, I didn't use `-a`, so the file wasn't actually committed.  So if the file isn't committed, then switching back to master branch won't revert it?

Comment: That's right. You can switch back to `issue57` to `git add foo` and `git commit -m "…"`